# How to get elements with same class from two separate arrays with one call?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a situation as follows:

```
<div class="milk">
    <span class="onion">1</span>
</div>
<div class="milk">
    <span class="onion">2</span>
</div>
<div class="milk">
    <span class="onion">3</span>
</div>

<div class="stone">
    <span class="onion">1</span>
</div>

<div class="stone">
    <span class="onion">2</span>
</div>

<script>
    var onions = [];
    var milk = [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '.milk' ));
    var stone = [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '.stone' ));

    milk.forEach( function( element, i ) {
        onions.push(element.querySelector( '.onion' ));
    });

    stone.forEach( function( element, i ) {
        onions.push(element.querySelector( '.onion' ));
    });
</script>
```

As you can see, I use a similar same statement to push `.onion` elements from the `milk` and `stone` elements. And here lies my question — out of curiosity, is there a way to push `onion` elements into array `onions` with one line or statement, without merging the two arrays first?

Assuming the following statement was valid (it's not), this is the kind of answer I'm looking for:

```
(stone, milk).forEach( function( element, i ) {
        onions.push(element.querySelector( '.onion' ));
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If your question is how to traverse two arrays with one call, then consider `concat`:

```
milk.concat(stone).forEach( /* callback */ )
```

Or with ES6 spread syntax:

```
[...milk, ...stone].forEach( /* callback */ )
```

If the reason for using `forEach` is to build a new array (`onions`), then consider using `map` instead:

```
onions = milk.concat(stone).map(function (elem) { 
    return elem.querySelector('.onion');
});
```

But for your particular query, you would better put the logic in the CSS selector using `querySelectorAll()`, which Ori Drori had proposed in his deleted answer:

```
onions = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.milk > .onion, .stone > .onion'));
```